# Moon gravity space low gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, estimation, moon

How is it possible that a man or woman without equipment will "float" on the moon, but a photo can be left lying on the surface without anchor and not float away?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding gravity on the moon.   A person does not merely float on the moon.  Yes, they can jump higher, but they still fall back down to the surface.  So something on the surface, like a rock or a paper, will sit there just like on Earth.

Comment: You don't float on the moon.

Comment: Ok thank you for explaining it to me. And apparently you are exactly correct, I was mistaken about the gravity on the moon.

Comment: And also you fall back very slowly, giving the illusion perhaps of floating

Comment: @Anjul, you may have the misconception that there is no gravity in a vacuum after watching the astronauts float around inside the space station.  Since the moon has no air, that would imply no gravity as well.  This assumption is definitely incorrect, as there is gravity acting on the international space station and on the moon.

Comment: So there is no wind on the moon? So if that is true then it must also be true that the footage of the flag blowing on the moon is a fake?

Answer (score 4):

Gravitational attraction on the Moon is about one sixth of what it is on Earth. This is due to the Moon's lesser mass. This means all people or objects will still fall downwards near the Moon's surface though they will fall slower than on Earth. If you weigh, for instance, 600 Newtons on Earth you would weigh about 100 Newtons on the Moon.

Comment: You would still have a mass of $60kg$ but the force exerted on it by the Moon will less than the Earth.  The same force as $10kg$ will experience on the Earth.

Comment: @badjohn  Yes mass is always the same, weight depends on net gravitational effects.

Comment: In day to day life, people commonly say "I weigh 60kg" but they don't really as kilograms measure mass.  Weight is a force and should be measured in Newtons.  Not important in day to day life as the conversion ratio is (almost) constant but relevant when you leave the Earth.

Comment: @AdrianHoward, why don't you change 'kilograms' to 'Newtons' because it is WRONG. Mass is constant. This may cause misunderstanding to beginners.

Comment: @ACB You are correct, I was trying to make it more understandable to the poster as most common scales measure pounds or kilos, and most people state their weight in pounds or kilos. I have edited it to be technically correct.